# Bazel remote cache analysis data

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bazel

I am running bazel (via bazelisk) inside a docker container on jenkins. Furthermore I use a remote cache. On subsequent runs with no changes I get 100% cache hits, but the analysis phase (~60seconds) runs everytime a new container is created.

Is there a way to cache the analysis data remotely aswell or am I forced to run bazel directly on the jenkins agent so it doesn't shut itself off after build completion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've got a similar issue with GitLab CI. I tried caching ~/.cache/bazel, but it looks like it's full of symlinks that are playing pretty badly with GitLab CI. You might have more luck with Jenkins if that's something you can do. Another thing is, I believe during the analysis phase, if you have third-party repositories that you fetch, that's the time it gets downloaded. It might still be downloading the repositories even though you're not building anything because of cache hits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/remote-caching.html#known-issues

this link describes that the state is stored in-memory and therefore can not be cached easily

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on profiling and load the resulting file into chrome://tracing, it'll show you what it's doing in the analysis phase.  This may or may not help you avoid those things.  I did this and found several things that could be avoided.