# Google Cloud Build - How to Cache Bazel?

Tags: caching, google-cloud-platform, bazel, google-cloud-build

I recently started using Cloud Build with Bazel.
So I have a basic `cloudbuild.yaml`

```
steps:
  - id: 'run unit tests'
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel
    args: ['test', '//...']
```

which runs all tests of my Bazel project.

But as you can see from this screenshot, every build takes around 4 minutes, although I haven't touched any code which would affect my tests.

[image: build duration]

Locally running the tests for the first time takes about 1 minute. But running the tests a second time, with the help of Bazels cache, it takes only a few seconds.

**So my goal is to use the Bazel cache with Google Cloud Build**

## Update

As suggested by [Thierry Falvo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4786620/thierry-falvo) I'v looked into those [recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds?hl=en). An thus I tried to the add the following to my `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args: ['cp', 'gs://cents-ideas-build-cache/bazel-bin', 'bazel-bin']

  - id: 'run unit tests'
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel
    args: ['test', '//...']

  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args: ['cp', 'bazel-bin', 'gs://cents-ideas-build-cache/bazel-bin']
```

Although I created the bucket and folder, I get this error:

```
CommandException: No URLs matched
```

[image: cloud build error]

Comment: Maybe this could help you : (https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds?hl=en) and (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/remote-caching.html#google-cloud-storage)

Comment: I've tried caching the files with Cloud Storage, but I get an error (I've updated my answer)

Comment: Try changing the name of the file as suggested [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/490#issuecomment-508809107). Try to use different names for the files being copied from Cloud Storage in a similar fashion to `args: ['cp', 'gs://[BUCKET-NAME]/bazelbin', 'previousbazelbin']` on the first step (that uses the result for the previous build). Make all the operations that use the `previousbazelbin` file and create the new `newbazelbin` and copy the new results back in the bucket `args: ['cp', 'newbazelbin', 'gs://[BUCKET-NAME]/bazelbin']`

Comment: Sounds good. But do you know how to make bazel use the `previousbazelbin` folder. And how can I produce a `newbazelbin` folder from the steps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that rather than cache discrete results (artifacts), you want to use GCS (cloud storage) as a [bazel remote cache](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/site/docs/remote-caching.md#user-content-google-cloud-storage).

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel
  args: ['test', '--remote_cache=https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucketname>', '--google_default_credentials', '--test_output=errors', '//...']
```

Comment: It worked and the test finished in 0.7 seconds. But the setup work before the test start took 4 minutes :o. Is this normal? Anything I can do about it?

Comment: I got similar results - the performance benefit was only small.  I also sometimes got consistency problems where I needed to clear the cache/bucket so I have left it turned off in my build for now.

Comment: It seems analysis phase at CI is executed fully, because of the known issue, and we cannot fix it with any kind of cache: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60292715/644496